# My App is crashing with reason Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT I am using below code , I am getting same crash log on Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety

```
if let val = userDict["userType"], let val = userDict["userID"],let val = userDict["audioStatus"],let val = userDict["ask"] {
    if userDict["userType"] as! String == "Host" {
                                             
        let userkey = snapshot.key as? String ?? ""
                            
        let keyExistsInHost = self.hostList[userkey] != nil // add new user to speaker and update existing speaker
                            
        if keyExistsInHost {
            userDict["isHighlighted"] = "No" as? AnyObject

            self.hostList.updateValue(userDict, forKey: userkey)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                let index = self.hostListUIArray.firstIndex(of: userkey) ?? 0
                let isIndexValid = self.hostListUIArray.indices.contains(index)
                if isIndexValid {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: index , section: 0)])// crashing at this line
                }
            }                          
        }
```

Comment: Is it actually crashing or have you just set a breakpoint (blue flag) on that line?

Comment: you could try this: `if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
                collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: index , section: 0)])
            }`

Comment: it's actually crashing and crashlog is reported to Firebase Crashlytics , not able to reproduce in Xcode system

Comment: Deactivate all breakpoints. Also writing this could save you from crashes :  `if userDict["userType"] as? String == "Host" {`.

Comment: does your app still crash with my suggested code? If yes, then the problem  will be in the `[IndexPath(row: index , section: 0)]`, is most likely in "index"

Comment: Why that complexity around checking for a valid index?  You can just say `if let index = self.hostListUIArray.firstIndex(of: userkey) {`

Comment: yeah, it's a bit like doing `let keyExistsInHost = self.hostList[userkey] != nil`, just using the last part in the following if is enough.